# How are Mono and Diglycerides metabolized without the Free Fatty Acids of Triglycerides?

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, lipids, energy-metabolism, food-chemistry

Having difficulty figuring out what the body does with ingested mono and diglycerides if the usual process of TAG metabolism includes the FFA released from the TAG returning to the MAG to recreate a TAG in the enterocyte, whereas with MAG and DAG consumption, those FFA don't exist. There are many studies (Nagao, 2000, Takatoshi, 2002 and others) confirming that DAG oil consumption leads to weight loss, which is seemingly obvious as the fat cannot be stored without the FFA getting repackaged into TAGs for storage in the adipose tissue. I have not found any studies on what actually happens to the MAGs in lieu of its normal course. I would much appreciate if someone could direct me to literature discussing this process or help me better understand it. Many thanks! Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the intestinal lumen, di- and triacylglycerol are hydrolysed to free fatty acid and monoglyceride by lipase.

These diffuse through the plasma membrane of enterocyte where they will   used to resynthetize triacylglycerol, and ultimately the lipoprotein chylomicron for transport into the general circulation.

Contrary to what your question seems to imply, the glycerol to which the free fatty acid are affixed is not necessarily coming from the food: glycerol is routinely produced by glycolysis. (This notably also happens in the adypocytes). There is no requirement that food contain a ratio three fatty acid to one glycerol to be fully absorbed - if the weight loss property of DAG are true, it may be through  a different mechanism.

Comment: My question was not where the glycerols come from as there are present in MAGs and DAGs as well. The question was that without the extra FFAs which exist in TAGs, the MAGs which are entering the enterocyte do not have the usual accompanying FFAs to re-synthesize into TAGs.

Comment: Hello! This question was deemed worth of an answer, so why not upvote it? [Vote early, vote often](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22/vote-early-vote-often?rq=1) to encourage new users and keep the community alive!